# AVL tree rotations

Tags: nodes, avl-tree

I have coded two helper functions to help with rotating the leaves of an AVL tree. The output still appears to be incorrect. Is there something I am missing?

Full snippet: http://pastebin.com/CEGQ8TX0

Helper functions:

```
AVLNode *RightRotate(AVLNode *N)
{
     AVLNode *M;
     M = N->left;
     N->left = M->right;
     M->right = N;  
     return M;
}

AVLNode *LeftRotate(AVLNode *N)
{
     AVLNode *L;
     L = N->right;
     N->right = L->left;
     L->left = N;  
     return L;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The subroutines `RightRotate` and `LeftRotate` look right. I think you probably need to double check when you're rotating a subtree and changing the root of it, whether the upper level of the subtree knows this, i.e. whether the relevant child pointer of the upper level is properly reassigned.

Comment: Input: 48 3
29 2
88 1
14 1
7 0
21 0
37 1
35 0
39 0
79 0
99 0
0 0
1 29
#

Comment: Current Output: ** After:  (48,2) (14,1) (7,0)

Comment: Expected Output: ** After:  (48,4) (14,3) (7,0)